# ASP.NET MVC - Linq Query with Count returns anonymous type. How to display in view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

So I'm writing a query as follows:

```
Dim assSummary = From a In db.Assignments
                         Join ur In db.UserRegions
                         On a.Origin.ID Equals ur.Region.ID
                         Where ur.User.ID = usrid
                         Group By a.Status.Description _
                         Into AssCount = Count() _
                         Select AssCount, Description
```

In the controller I can return the data easily as follows:

```
For Each c In assSummary
    MsgBox(c.Description & " " & c.AssCount)
Next
```

If I pass the object through to the view using Viewdata("assSummary") = assSummary, how do I display the data? Every method I've tried results in messages about 'VB$AnonymousType_7(Of Integer,String) and I don't know how to retrieve the data from the anonymous type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the directives of your page view, you can turn option strict off and use the late-bound dynamic functionality against the anonymous types as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" ContentType="application/rss+xml" 
     CompilerOptions="/optionstrict-" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```

See
http://www.thinqlinq.com/Default/Binding-Anonymous-Types-in-MVC-Views.aspx for a fuller sample/explanation.